# Is there a javascript library can handle an entire page slide?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

When we are building html5 web app or ios hybrid app,we need to make an effect like the views' transition in an ios app.

Such as : http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

In the past I use jquery mobile or sencha touch to handle it.

But,you know,jquery mobile depends on many libraries or css.(Like: jquery, jquerymobile.css etc.) and sencha touch is too heavy.

I just wanna find a simple javascript library which can help me to handle this problem.

I also wish this library is pure and easy to use.

Is there a javascript library can handle this problem?:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you: [HTML Page Slide Without a Framework](http://www.terrenceryan.com/blog/post.cfm/html-page-slide-without-a-framework)

The solution is pretty lightweight and is powered by a little AJAX, some CSS transitions, and CSS transition events. It's also important to note that this only works with WebKit. (This case is for a mobile application with PhoneGap targeting Android and iOS, so it only need WebKit compatibility.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this one?

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html

jQuery should generaly be the best choice as it'll ensure it works cross browser and platform .

Comment: Emm...this demo shows slides in a single page.But I want,it's that when I use <a> element to link to another page,the page transition effect can be slide.Just an entire page slide.:-)

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna take a look at [Swipe](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe), especially since this will also be for iOS, because it detects the swipes and [the demo](http://swipejs.com/) shows support for slides.

There was some other good solutions presented here, on Stack Overflow, on this question: [Sliding An Entire Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403004/sliding-an-entire-web-page) You might want to take a look at the answers there, the accepted one does the sliding for entire pages

[edit]Depending on your skills, you could try to make your own vanilla (pure) javascript functions for the sliding. That's what I ended up doing, using the html5's translate3d css property.

For example, here's the function I use to generate the css codes:

```
//generates transformation styles for Opera, Chrome, Firefox and IE
function genTransform (x, y, z, dur) {
    var genStyle = '-webkit-transform: translate3d(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px, ' + z + 'px); -webkit-transition: ' + dur + 'ms;' + 
                '-moz-transform: translate3d(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px, ' + z + 'px); -moz-transition: ' + dur + 'ms;' + 
                '-ms-transform: translate3d(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px, ' + z + 'px); -ms-transition: ' + dur + 'ms;' + 
                '-o-transform: translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px); -o-transition: ' + dur + 'ms;' +
                'transform: translate3d(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px, ' + z + 'px); transition: ' + dur + 'ms;';

    return genStyle;
}
```

I then apply the style to my divs to get them to slide according to my needs. It's actually very simple if you only slide between a set number of pages