# Sliding in Web Pages

Tags: html, css, slide

I'm looking for an easy way to slide in entire pages, from right to left and back, much like in iOS.

I already came across a variety of solutions, also on this site, but none of them seemed to function the way i wanted. There is also a two year old question ["Sliding An Entire Web Page"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403004/sliding-an-entire-web-page) by someone else, but that turned out to be just two pages side by side.

---

My main problems are:

- I can not set up two DIVs side by side with one hidden, because I
  have more than one subpage.
- I can not use the jQuery Cycle Plugin, as    it is a responsive page
  and should not be static.
- I'd prefer a solution that is not based on a framework if possible. But don't bother linking me to [HTML Page Slide Without a Framework](http://css.dzone.com/articles/html-page-slide-without). Tried it, but unlike his Demo, the Source code from github didn't work.

---

**Again, I'm trying to slide in whole pages, not content within a page. It is not a mobile site.**

Thank you in advance, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not possible to perform animation on navigation. Everything that animates together must be a part of the same page - even if just technically and temporarily. I suggest that you use the 2yo question.

Comment: Oh i did not know that. Yet that solution is still not possible since there are more than two pages.

Comment: You could move the pages around dynamically or even fetch them just before the animation.

Comment: Moving them around could be a good way, but not in this case, as it is a portfolio site with lots of big images and that would take forever to load. Fetching them sounds promising, though i must admit i have no idea about how that works. Would you mind briefly explaining it?

Comment: 1) when the user clicks a link, create a new div `#next-page` at `left:100%` and load the target there. 2) when the load is complete, animate `#cur-page` to `left:-100%` and `#next-page` to `left:0` 3) when the animation is complete, remove `#cur-page` and rename `#next-page` to `#cur-page`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple demo http://jsbin.com/odivuz/3/edit which use jQuery `animate` to impelement the page transition. The `body` width is calculated when the event fired.

Comment: Thank you! Basically it works as requested, but is there any way to improve the smoothness?

Comment: You can change the length of duration in the `animate` function, using _easing_ or use jQuery UI to extend the animate API. This reference from jQuery doc may help http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: tested different durations and managed to improve it a bit, still "shaky" though. Also causes problems when the back button is used. I think i'll go for the fetching solution as suggested above, if i can figure it out somehow...