# Errors when trying to create a page with horizontally sliding divs that are the size of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, sliding

I'm attempting to use code from this page http://madesignuk.com/uploader/ which can be found here: [Sliding An Entire Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403004/sliding-an-entire-web-page) but I'm trying to simplify it.

Here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/QZCZh/6/

Now, I'm obviously running into problems - I can't make the next and back links appear, and the divs are still stacked vertically even though `float:left` is there. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Why dont you just find a simple jquery plugin for a slideshow?

Comment: You are missing jquery include. `$.browser` is removed from jquery 1.9, http://jsfiddle.net/QZCZh/7/