# JQuery: Sliding Divs - Sliding to the 2nd from the 1st div is fine but breaks after that

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm attempting to integrate code seen on this site: http://madesignuk.com/uploader/ from this post: [Sliding An Entire Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403004/sliding-an-entire-web-page) into my site.

So far, I've gotten the divs to animate. The transition to the first div is fine, but when going to a new div, either forward or backward breaks, and the screen doesn't travel the whole distance.

Here's the code I'm using, although it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/QZCZh/8/

Adding some alerts to my code shows that the `$(".content").css("left")` value is different than what it should be after the transition.

I.E:
The:

```
 $(".content").animate({
      left: (currPos - (this.windowWidth) + this.scrollbar) + 'px'
 }, 'slow');
```

section shows that `(currPos - (this.windowWidth) + this.scrollbar)` is 1519px before the transistion. However, after the transistion `$(".content").css("left")` returns -1898.75px, when it should return -1519px. I've looked for about an hour. and I can't seem to find the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The sliding on your site works fine for me...

Comment: It does for me as well on the JSFiddle. However, on my actual site, it breaks.

Comment: Unless I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, your actual site works for me.

Comment: The snippet works with me too, what's your site so we can take a look there ? also, why is currPos multiplied by 1 ?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's multiplied by 1, I just copy and pasted from the site. =P My site is a rails app on my computer, so I can't really show  it to you. I'll try to get something up on JSFiddle.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock None of the links I posted are the actual site. I'm making a rails app on my local computer, and trying to integrate this code. It works fine in the JSFiddle, but unfortunately isn't working for me on my app.

Comment: Here's basically what I'm doing, but it still works here, but not on my site. http://jsfiddle.net/QZCZh/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out by using percentages.

http://jsfiddle.net/QZCZh/11/

```
$(".content").animate({
     left: "+=" + movePercent + "%"
}, 'slow');
```

EDIT: I was subtracting the scrollbar width rather than adding it. Everything works now.